# How to fit a regression for log-normal with gamlss

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, gamlss

Since my original question was to R-code-specific I'm trying to rewrite it:

I want to make a regression where my dependent variable `y` should follow a log-normal-distribution influenced by the explanatory variable `x` where the mean and variance changes across the observation.

Since log-normal doesn't belong to the exponential-family I can't try a glm.
Then I found gamlss which should exactly do the trick.

I was looking for some paper explaining the theory a little deeper - especially in my case of log-normal and where all the parameters of the distribution are  functions of the explanatory variables.

First of all I would like to know if there is a formula like the one below for an ordinary linear regression to calculate `y` after fitting:

[image]

But my biggest problem is, that I have no idea on how to handle that the moments of `y` change across the observation of `x`.
So let's say I have the following:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the regression via R and its `gamlss`-package.

There I start with `gamlss(y~x,familiy=LOGNO())` and then one has the possibility the make `sigma` depending on `x` via `sigma.formula=~` but no option for `mu`. So is it even possible in general?

Here is my code:

```
library(gamlss)

y<-c(1495418, 1684470, 1997120, 1901727, 2070008, 2213829, 2364602, 2333710, 2491570, 2540110, 2620947, 2761075, 2943475, 2854544)
x<-c(3932300, 4119100, 4354400, 4483752, 4585303, 4803234, 4989701, 5177605, 5380031, 5494672, 5606376, 5783627, 6015992, 6171564)

fm<-gamlss(y~x,familiy=LOGNO())
summary(fm)
fitted(fm)
residuals(fm)
y-fitted(fm) #How come this aren't the residuals?

fitted(fm,"mu")
fitted(fm,"sigma")
```

Comment: I think your friend gave bad advice. You seem to be asking for R code and not raising a statistical question. There can be questions that don't fit CV or SO, but that's the way it is. http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says more.

Comment: You may be right for parts of the question but for example I can not find any paper stating a formula on the relation between `y` and `x` in case of log-normal and also the fact if it is even possible to perform the regression with the desired dependency on mean and variance should be a valid question for CV.

Comment: Please edit your Q to make it more software-neutral, then. This reads like a request for code.

Comment: I agree with @gung. It really needs rewriting from the title onwards.

Comment: Tiny answer for future reference: By default the residuals returned by `residuals(gamlsObject)` are $z$-scores - check `?residuals.gamlss` for more info.